# Can I have an abstract base class for my tornado.testing.AsyncTestCase tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tornado

Is it possible to have base classes that define tests in tornado that are themselves not run as tests?

Let's say I have the following minimal example as a base class:

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase, gen_test
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest

class AbstractTestCase(AsyncTestCase):
    def set_parameters(self):
        #Set some parameter value here: self.uri = ...
        raise NotImplementedError

    @gen_test
    def test_common_functionality(self):
        req = HTTPRequest(self.uri, method = "GET")
        response = yield self.client.fetch(req, raise_error=False)
        self.assertEqual(200, response.code)
```

Now, I would like to make several test cases that inherit from this, define their own value for self.uri...and have some specific tests of their own. Like this:

```
class ConcreteTestCase(AbstractTestCase):
    def set_parameters(self):
        self.uri = "www.stackoverflow.com"

    @gen_test
    def test_some_other_thing(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 1+1)
```

However, when I try to run this, the AbstractTestCase is also run on its own, giving an error (the NotImplementedError). This happens even when I only try to run the inheriting tests.

Is there any way around this issue, or do I have to duplicate the functionality in each test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with multiple inheritance. The abstract class doesn't need to extend AsyncTestCase as long as that class is in the inheritance hierarchy at runtime.

```
class AbstractTestCase(object):
    def set_parameters(self):
        #Set some parameter value here: self.uri = ...
        raise NotImplementedError

    @gen_test
    def test_common_functionality(self):
        req = HTTPRequest(self.uri, method = "GET")
        response = yield self.client.fetch(req, raise_error=False)
        self.assertEqual(200, response.code)

class ConcreteTestCase(AbstractTestCase, AsyncTestCase):
    def set_parameters(self):
        self.uri = "www.stackoverflow.com"

    @gen_test
    def test_some_other_thing(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 1+1)
```

This is admittedly a little weird and `mypy` type checking doesn't like it. But it's simple and it works, and I haven't found a `mypy`-friendly alternative that I like.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to mostly work. I had to replace self.assertEqual(...) by regular assert, but it does the job.

Comment: Although on a further note, it is kind of annoying not to be able to use assertEqual and the like...

Comment: `self.assertEqual` works here, thanks to dynamic typing. It doesn't look like AbstractTestCase has this method, but when the final class is instantiated the methods are there.

Comment: You are correct of course. I was just looking at my editor complaining and didn't think further.

Answer (score 0):

## CLI

```sh
python3 -m tornado.testing ConcreteTestCase.ConcreteTestCase
```

## testmain.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import unittest
from tornado.testing import main


def all():
    cases = ['ConcreteTestCase.ConcreteTestCase']
    return unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromNames(cases)

main()
```

[test/runtests.py](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/test/runtests.py) is a good example.

Comment: This does not work for me, it still tries to run the abstract test case and gets a NotImplementedError

Comment: @andresti you just only need to run tests you want?If so, append method name after class name like this `python3 -m tornado.testing ConcreteTestCase.ConcreteTestCase.test_some_other_thing`

Comment: That actually does work. But what I would really like is to run all the tests I have, not go one-by-one.